# Aceitar apenas uma virgula no Textbox c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Ola estou com meu Textbox decimal assim:

```
      <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"  KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"  
        Style="{StaticResource MeuTextBoxValor}" Height="23" Margin="1"   
        Text="{Binding Peso,  NotifyOnValidationError=true,  StringFormat={}{0:#0.00##}, 
    ConverterCulture='pt-BR', 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
```

Quando coloca uma virgula nesse campo fica assim

> 0,,00

E quando começa a escrever ele escreve assim

> 0,22,00

Gostaria de tirar esse ",00" a direita. 
Ja tentei dar um `TextBox.Text.Replace(",00","")` porem ele continua a colocar.

Comment: Experimente alterar o seu `StringFormat` para `{0:#,##0.00}`.

Comment: Mesma coisa João

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez seja melhor validar o valor aquando a introdução de texto, para evitar introdução incorreta de caracteres.

Para isso deve subscrever o evento `PreviewTextInput`:

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInput" />
```

No método `PreviewTextInput` validamos a vírgula:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    bool approvedDecimalPoint = false;

    if (e.Text == ",")
    {
        if (!((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains(","))
            approvedDecimalPoint = true;
    }

    if (!(char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1) || approvedDecimalPoint))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Ele ainda continua colocando duas virgulas.

Comment: Certo, editei a resposta para incluir uma condição.

Comment: Ainda a mesma coisa, porque o e e.Text sempre sera a virgula.  Mesmo se eu pegar do TextBox.Text ele ainda vai dar um porque ainda nao pois a virgula.

Comment: Resposta editada e reduzida. Antes coloquei o `e.Text` indevidamente. Deveria ser `((TextBox)sender).Text`.

Comment: Deu certo agora sim :-) era isso mesmo João